# Cancel old Promise.resolve if same method called multiple times with given timeframe

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, axios

I am using Promise and axios in react to call POST api and fetch list of records.
Issue is when multiple API calls triggered then any one which response last is getting is updating state.
Where i want to use only last called API response.
Exp : call API 3 times with different postbody, in case first call response take time than 2nd & 3rd then callback is using response of 1st call to setstate, instead i want to forget 1 and second call and consider last call response only.

Following is example
Common File

```
const apiService = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://example.com/api/,
});

    function post(postData) {
        return Promise.resolve(apiService.post('https://example.com/api/getuserlist', postData, {
            headers: {'Authorization': `Bearer sdfsdfsdf-cvdfs`}
        }));
    }
```

Service File

```
static getUsers(postData) {
   return post(postData);
}
```

React Component

```
 function getUsersList = (Filters )=>{
       getUsers({ "Filters": Filters }).then((response) => {
           this.setState({ users: response.data})
       })
    }
```

Problem is when getUsersList get called multiple time whichever is last response is getting set to users state, where last call should be users list.

Answer (score 0):

It's not yet possible to actually cancel promises in JavaScript (though there is a [proposal](https://github.com/bergus/promise-cancellation) for it).

However, it *is* possible to implement the functionality you want in React. Consider something like this:

```js
// state shape:
// {
//   loading: boolean
//   apiPromise: null | Promise<{ data: User[] }>
//   users: User[]
// }

getUsersList = async (Filters) => {
  // raw promise - don't await it yet
  const apiPromise = getUsers({ Filters })

  this.setState({ apiPromise, loading: true })

  // _here_ we await it
  const response = await apiPromise

  // check if it's the most recent API request we made
  if (this.state.apiPromise === apiPromise) {
    this.setState({ users: response.data, loading: false })
  } else {
    console.log("stale val discarded:", users)
  }
}
```

[CodeSandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-wilbur-zpv79?file=/src/App.js) - simplified example with mocked API and single `val` rather than list of `users`. Try clicking the button many times in quick succession and watch the console output.

Comment: Added workaround in the same way ie , compare filters in then to check its latest response. So state will be set only when last response is received

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand, is that a question? @CyberAbhay

Answer (score 0):

Using [CPromise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/c-promise2) wrapper the code might look like this [See the live demo](https://runkit.com/digitalbrainjs/cancel-axios):

```
const CPromise = require('c-promise2');
const axios= require('axios');

// Let's wrap axios get method to the CPromise
function get(url){
    return new CPromise((resolve, reject, {onCancel})=>{
        axios.get(url, {
            cancelToken: new axios.CancelToken(function executor(cancel) {
                onCancel(cancel)
            })
        }).then(resolve, reject);
    });
}

let chain= null;

function makeRequest(url){
    chain && chain.cancel();
    chain= get(url).then((response)=> {
            console.log(`Response ${JSON.stringify(response.data)}`);
        }, function (err) {
            console.warn(`Error: ${err}`);
        }
    );
}

// some endpoint with a delay of 3 seconds for a response
const url= "https://run.mocky.io/v3/753aa609-65ae-4109-8f83-9cfe365290f0?mocky-delay=3s";

makeRequest(url);
// make the same request again, abort the previous
setTimeout(()=> makeRequest(url), 1000);
```

But since the package is in early beta stage, you can use the plain cancellation token, provided by axios [See Axios documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation)